# Send key to component

Tags: delphi

I'm writing an application where the user will be entering data in different languages into a TcxGrid. To facilitate entering of keys not on a normal keyboard (á or ¿) I decided to add the ability for the user to add a button, which when pressed would send a character directly to the grid.

Basically the button gets pressed, the caption on the button is the character to send to the grid. Right now my only way of doing this would be to get the active grid cell, copy the text there, append the character to add and then set the grid value to the new string. This doesn't seem ideal.

Any ideas on a clean way to do this?

Comment: Windows already has facilities for this. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: If it's a language the user already types in with any frequency, then the user will simply switch to that keyboard layout in the OS, and your "keys" will be redundant. If it's a language the user doesn't usually type, then the "keys" you provide probably won't be used either; instead, the user will go find a Web site or document with the desired text, copy, and paste. Is this something users have actually requested of your product, or are you making up solutions in search of a problem?

Comment: Switching the keyboard layout in the OS would get tedious fast. The idea is for the user to able to enter a phrase in english, then the same phrase translated into another language. Copy and pasting will probably be used quite a bit for phrases but having a quick simple way to add foreign characters seems like a good idea to me.

@DavidHeffernan: Do you mean something other than the virtual on screen keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can get the handle of the control, you can post messages to the control which indicate typing.

```
PostMessage(Edit1.Handle, WM_CHAR, Ord('A'), 0);
```

I'm sure there's a slicker way to do it, but I got your characters doing this off of using "Character Map":

```
const
  testchar1 = 'Á';
  testchar2 = '¿';
begin
  PostMessage(Edit1.Handle, WM_CHAR, Ord(testchar1), 0);
  PostMessage(Edit1.Handle, WM_CHAR, Ord(testchar2), 0);
end;
```

If you need virtual scan codes, use WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP messages.

Comment: I tried using the grid.Handle not expecting much and it didn't work. I'm looking for how to find the active edit item to use it's handle but haven't found it yet. Thanks for the PostMessage tip, that seems like it will work find if I can get a handle.

Comment: I found a way to make it work. I'll mark this as the answer if nothing else comes up because the solution still seems gimmicky. I ended up keeping track of the last edit item by using the OnInitEdit event for TcxGridBandedTableView object, then I use use PostMessage with that handle.